# Is it possible to modfiy prefetchable memory for a PCI bridge?

Tags: linux, pci-express

The previous FPGA allowed for 0xFFFFF amount of memory.
The newer FPGA has double the memory.

The Linux pci driver is able to assign the correct memory space for each pci bus.

```
[    1.882289] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xf8000000-0xf81fffff]
[    1.882296] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    1.882302] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf8000000-0xf81fffff]
[    1.882308] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xf8200000-0xf83fffff]
[    1.882315] pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    1.882319] pci 0000:00:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf8200000-0xf83fffff]
```

However the amount of prefetchable memory for the bridge is half the size needed. It's still the same size that was used by the previous hardware.

```
[root@lsa /]# lspci -v -s 00:01.0
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device 6820 (rev 0a) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: f8000000-f81fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000-000fffff <-------------------
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00

[root@lsa /]# lspci -v -s 00:04.0
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device 6820 (rev 0a) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: f8200000-f83fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000-000fffff <-------------------
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
```

**How can I change the size of the prefetchable memory for my PCI bridges to 0x1fffff from 0xfffff?**